# Control Deserializing Json Properties via Attributes?

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have json that is returned similar to:

```
{
  "access_token" : "....",
  "token_type" : "....",
  "expires_in" : "...."
}
```

I have a class that I want to deserialize this into, but the fields are:

```
public string AccessToken { get; set; }
public string TokenType { get; set; }
public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
```

I have attempted DataMember(Name="access_token") and the like for the 3 properties, but any time I have attempted to bind to it, it fails (int is 0, strings are null). The only way I've been able to get it to work is a bit... wordy:

```
var test = JObject.Parse(result);
var test2 = new AuthorizeToken() {
  AccessToken = test["access_token"].ToString(),
  ExpiresIn = Convert.ToInt32(test["expires_in"]),
  TokenType = test["token_type"].ToString()
};
```

When I do this, test2 is populated appropriately, but I'd prefer do some type of

```
Deserialize<AuthorizeToken>(result);
```

with Json.NET

Comment: I think [`[JsonPropertyAttribute("access_token")]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute__ctor_1.htm) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you give your class decorations ( `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`) and give some context ?

Comment: vcsjones, you're right. Want to make it an answer?